# Axios post request parameters to backend are undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm creating a simple ReactJs and I created a Searchbar component that does a post request when the user types something into the searchbar. This is the function that does the call:

```
const searchApi = searchTerm => 
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/findMovie', {
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
params: searchTerm
});
```

and it is being called in the onChange function like this:

```
handleInput = async (ev) => {
const value = ev.target.value;
const resultsBody = await searchApi(ev.target.value);
```

and this is what I do in my `server.js` file:

```
app.post('/findMovie', (req, res) => {
console.log('request:', req.params);

// axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey='+ 
// process.env.OMDB_API_KEY + '&s=' +)
})
```

I expected the `console.log` in the backend to show me the request parameters so that I can later do my api call to the external api and return the results, but the `console.log` show an empty object.

I'm quite new to this but shouldn't I do a post request for something like this? I also tried the same with a get request but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is caused by naming confusion between axios and express. `params` property in axios is sent as search parameters in the url.

In express url search parameters are available through `query` property, not `params`. So, try this:

```
app.post('/findMovie', (req, res) => {
  console.log('request:', req.query);
})
```

`params` property on an express request object refers to named route parameters, as in `/users/:userId/edit`.

More on that in express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

**Update**

Also, in order for the `axios.post` method to work properly, you need to change your call a little bit. It expects the post data a second argument. Since you're not sending any data in the body, you can provide an empty object:

```
const searchApi = searchTerm => 

    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/findMovie', {} /* <-- this guy */, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    params: searchTerm
  });
```

Without it, your config object is wrongfully treated as post data.

Comment: Nice, now I'm getting the value that I want in the console.log, but I had to change both to a get request. Is the get request what I need or does it have to be a post request because I had the impression that whenever you send data to the backend it has to be a post request.

Comment: You can send POST or GET (ore any other method, like PUT, DELETE, etc) to backend, it depends how it's done, for example here you have `app.post`, so it will only work for POST, but feel free to use any method you need. Look for documentation on REST APIs where each actions corresponds to a method.

Comment: I'd stick to post when sending data to the server. You can still do that with `axios.post` with a little change. The thing is that post method expects data object as a second argument and config as third. In your example you're passing config as a second, so it treats it as data. Add an empty object as a second argument and you should be good.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it. It seems that it works. Thanks @GlebKost

Answer (score 2):

Try your axios function like this, set the `params` property as an object:

```
const searchApi = searchTerm => 
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/findMovie', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    params: { searchTerm }
});
```

And on the server you need to use `req.query`:

```
app.post('/findMovie', (req, res) => {
    console.log('request:', req.query);
})
```

You should be able to get the param as `req.query.searchTerm`

Comment: I guess it doesn't work with a post request, I'm getting the data when I change it to a get request.