# cannot retrieve data from react axios post to express node, tried all I could find

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, mongoose

I'm trying to do something quite straightforward, here's my code:

```
// in react
async function postAxios_product(formData) {
// formdata is a string, for example "WWWWWWW", from clicking on an input
    try {
      const obj2post = {name:formData}
      console.log("post to api/product:" + JSON.stringify(obj2post))  // shows {"name":"WWWWWWW"} for example 
      await axios.post(`${server}/product`, obj2post,  {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"} ) 
      .then(set_products( [...get_products, obj2post])) // update react state
    }
    catch (e) {console.error('Error in postAxios_product' + e.message);} 
  }

// in express node 
app.post(`/product`, async (req, res) => {
    console.log("inside post product")
    console.log(req.data) // undefined
    console.log(req.body) // undefined
    console.log(req.request) // {}
    console.log(req.params) // {}
      let product = await Product.create(req.data);
      return res.status(201).send({  error: false,   product  })
    })
```

I looked up the answers in [Axios post request parameters to backend are undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739951/axios-post-request-parameters-to-backend-are-undefined) , see req.query, req.data, etc

I also tried:

```
const {data: json}  = await axios.post(`${server}/product`, obj2postStr,  {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"} )
```

as suggested in [Node receive post json from axios post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656728/node-receive-post-json-from-axios-post),
but that doesn't work either

Comment: try { headers :{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" , "Content-Type": "application/json"} }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to install and use `bodyParser` on your nodejs server

First run `npm i body-parser` on your server folder

Then `require` `body-parser` into your server file

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

Then after initializing your app add these 2 lines

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This should give you access to the request body by accessing `req.body`

Comment: Works at last! 

Note that calling app.use should be done before calling the req.body . First time round I had the Mongo stuff in a separate file, and all the requires were in the top, before the app.use statements, so it only worked after moving the app.use up towards the top.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [cors](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) to **express app** which helps for `request` mapping/parsing

```js
...

app.use(cors())

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```